# Show values at a Tabbed Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I would like to know how to show up values which I take from an `extends AppCompatActivity` to an `extends Fragment`. The second one is one Tab from Tabbed activity and I can only calls `extends Fragment` java file.Into class I have 3 `TextViews` that contain the values which I want to print.Below is a piece of the code I am referring to.

```
    public class Tab1Signal extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextView tv1,tv2,tv3;
        int value=0,dbm=0;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tab1);
            tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
            tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.info2);
            tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.info3);
            TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            tm.listen(new Tab1Signal2(this), PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
            String opname="\nOperator ID:"+" "+tm.getNetworkOperator();
            opname=opname+"\nOperator Name:"+" "+tm.getNetworkOperatorName();
            int phoneType=tm.getPhoneType(),networkType=tm.getNetworkType();
            String ptype="",ntype="";
            switch(phoneType) {
                case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA:
                    ptype="\nPhone Type: CDMA\n";
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM:
                    ptype="\nPhone Type: GSM\n";
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_SIP:
                    ptype="\nPhone Type: SIP\n";
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE:
                    ptype="\nPhone Type: NONE\n";
                    break;
            }
          tv1.setText(opname+ptype+ntype);
}
```

And the second class

```
public class Tab1Values extends Fragment{
    public Tab1Values() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Thank you